# what is a node on a queue added from a tree, a pointer or a copy of the node?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree, queue

A tree traversal algorithm involves adding nodes on a tree onto a queue. Say I added the rootNode to queue. After the `queue.add(rootNode)` operation, the rootNode now existing on the queue, is it a copy of rootNode on the tree or just a pointer to the rootNode on the tree?

I did not provide a custom concrete implementation for Queue interface, I only used
`private Queue<MultiwayTreeNode<T>> multiwayTreeNodeQueue = new LinkedList<MultiwayTreeNode<T>>();`

Comment: Show us your ```Queue.class``` implementation to be definite on my answer here . Usually it is a reference to the element. So even if you change the rootNode Object's value, this will be reflected as is when you go about doing ```queue.element()```

Comment: ```StackOverflowPojo pojo = new StackOverflowPojo("1");
        Queue<StackOverflowPojo> queue = new ArrayDeque();
        queue.add(pojo);
        pojo.setId("3");
        System.out.println(queue.element()); //prints 3``` This is a simple example using ```ArrayDeque.class``` to point out my answer

Comment: Going by your answer, then the pojo on the queue (queue.pojo) is actually another object that points to the pojo on StackOverflowPojo (StackOverflowPojo.pojo). Hence, changing the value of queue.pojo doesn't affect the value of StackOverflowPojo.pojo, but not vice versa. So, can I conclude that queue.pojo is a pointer?

Comment: Unsure what you mean ```StackOverflowPojo.pojo``` or ```Queue.pojo```. Check the sample code i have put on my answer to help you understand. Added the Class for ```StackOverflowPojo.class```

Comment: Note that your StackOverflow class is only a POJO or a node in the case of a data structure. So, let's say I've added  pojo to a tree, ```multiwayTree1.addRootNode(pojo)``` so that pojo now lives on multiwayTree1. On executing ```queue.add(pojo) afterwards, I assumed that this statement created another object and this new object points to pojo which live on multiwayTree1 so that there are two objects in play here where the one on the queue points to the object on the multiwayTree. That's what I mean by StackOverflowPojo.pojo and Queue.pojo, just to differentiate between the two objects.

Comment: We would have to see your code to answer. It can be coded either way. I am voting to close this question because we haven’t got enough information to give a qualified answer.

Comment: @Ireti Your code uses LinkedList Implementation as a Queue. As long as this is true, you are referring the same object in memory. My answer clears that up by modifying the mutable object.

Answer (score 1):

Objects are usually passed by reference in Java. But as said by another user, to be definite would need to see your implementation of queue.

Answer (score 1):

> **Java is always pass by reference unless you do a copy of your objects so new references in stack and memory in heap is created of the same Object**

To answer your question. `Queue` is an interface in java and normal implementations of Queue donot shallow copy the elements entirely and create a new set of references in memory. Going by this assumption, your object will definitely be prone to changes inside the queue irrespective as your Queue Implementation would be storing only references to the Object in Heap Memory

EDIT:

So a simple program would do the following (modify the object). I'm using the `LinkedList<>()` as you mentioned

```
StackOverflowPojo pojo = new StackOverflowPojo("1");
Queue<StackOverflowPojo> queue = new LinkedList();
queue.add(pojo);
   pojo.setId("3"); //MODIFICATION 1
System.out.println(queue.element()); //prints 3
   queue.element().setId("4"); //MODIFICATION 2
System.out.println(pojo); //prints 4
```

```
class StackOverflowPojo{
 private String id; 
 public StackOverflowPojo(String id){
  this.id = id;
 }
 @Override public String toString(){
   this.id;
 }
}
```